# Actually Download File from S3 bucket to local machine

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get an s3 file from my bucket using the following function:

```js
async Export()
 {
   const myKey = '...key...'
   const mySecret = '...secret...'
  AWS.config.update(
    {
      accessKeyId: myKey,
      secretAccessKey: mySecret
    }
  );

  var s3 = new AWS.S3();

  s3.getObject({
    Bucket: '...bucket...',
    Key: '...filepath...'
  },
  function(error, data)
  {
    if (error != null)
    {
      alert("Failed to retrieve object: " + error)
    }
    else {
      alert("Loaded " + data.ContentLength + " bytes")
    }
  })
 }
```

and the message telling me that I have loaded a file of some number of bytes. However, the main goal is to get the file onto my local machine, would I need to have some sort of file stream going on here or something?

#### Notes

Using angular typescript not angular js

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are getting the file as stream. Instead of saving the file as stream, you can get the s3 signed url and can download file from that steam by creating anchor link and clicking that dynamically. Below code can help you.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const s3 = new AWS.S3()
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'your access key', secretAccessKey: 'you secret key'})

const myBucket = 'bucket-name'
const myKey = 'path/to/your/key/file.extension'
const signedUrlExpireSeconds = 60 * 5 // your expiry time in seconds.

const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
  Bucket: myBucket,
  Key: myKey,
  Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds
})
```

Use this URL in the front-end to trigger download:

```
function download(url){
  $('<iframe>', { id:'idown', src:url }).hide().appendTo('body').click();
}
$("#downloadButton").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'example.com/your_end_point',
    success: function(url){
      download(url);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: the second code block would go where exactly though, I am using angular for all of this if that helps

Comment: You can write custom JS code anywhere in your application. but that file should be loaded with page load.

Answer (score 0):

Took some research, but I found that using the backend is the best approach to this problem. I was creating an anchor tag that upon clicking should download the s3 url, but instead it would open a new tab with the object. The problem was my Reponse Content Disposition. Here is my approach to getting it to download directly to the filesystem:

Backend (I use Django and boto3):

```
    def get_file(self, obj):      
        client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                              aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

        return client.generate_presigned_url(
            'get_object',
            Params={
                'Bucket': settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
                'Key': obj.key,
                'ResponseContentDisposition': 'attachment',
            },
            ExpiresIn=600)
```

Frontend (using Angular):

```
<a [href]="what_i_returned_from_backend" [download]="answer.png" target="_self" rel="noopener noreferrer">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a list of files in a Spring + Angular web app, that users can download.
When you click on file name, UI asks API for a temporary download link, which is generated by AmazonS3.generatePresignedUrl().

```
  public String generateUrlByKey(String key) {
    log.debug("S3 - Get file OutputStream by key: {}", key);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new Date());
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest request = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(s3Properties.getBucket(),
                                                                          key,
                                                                          HttpMethod.GET);
    request.setExpiration(calendar.getTime());

    ResponseHeaderOverrides headerOverrides = new ResponseHeaderOverrides();
    headerOverrides.setContentDisposition("attachment");
    request.withResponseHeaders(headerOverrides);

    return amazonS3.generatePresignedUrl(request).toString();
  }
```

Note the line: **headerOverrides.setContentDisposition("attachment")**;
Setting header ContentDisposition as attachment is necessary, that files are downloaded instead of opened, when clicking on a file link.

I am clicking on file links dynamically, after fetching the link in UI:

```
  this.fileService.getTempUrlByFileId($event.id).subscribe({
    next: (url) => {
      const link: HTMLAnchorElement = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = url;
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
  });
```

getTempUrlByFileId implementation:

```
  getTempUrlByFileId(id: number): Observable<string> {
    const url = `${this.API}/${id}`
    // @ts-ignore
    return this.http.get<string>(url, { responseType: 'text' });
  }
```